# Replace several html absolute path strings with relative path

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

I have an html file and several jpgs that I retrieve from a database.  This html has several *img scr="..."* tags and each tag has an absolute path based upon the customer's url.  **My task is to replace each of those absolute paths with relative path for viewing after I extract the html and images files to local drive.**

For example, I have:

```
...
<img src="www.something.com\images\image1.jpg">
...
<img src="www.something.com\images\image2.jpg">
...
<img src="www.something.com\images\image3.jpg">
```

And I want:

```
...
<img src="image1.jpg">
...
<img src="image2.jpg">
...
<img src="image3.jpg">
```

Challenges:

1) The customer's urls will be all the same within the html file, however, another html will have a different customer url.  So I cannot simply look for the same string in every html.
2) Must be done in java, using java's native libraries.  Cannot use Jsoup or any other 3rd party jar.

Question:

I presume replaceAll using regular expressions would be the way to go, but not sure how to write it for a varying search string in the case of htmls for different customers.  Although I have scoured the stack submissions for an answer, I have not found one with this unique scenario and challenges.

So my question is, what would be the best way to accomplish this task?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I appreciate all the answers big and small.  And those that were here and then removed.  I will try each one.

Answer (score 0):

REgex:

```
(<img src=\").*?\\\\([^\\\\\"]*\">)
```

Replacement string:

```
$1$2
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/nA6hN9/14)

Comment: I do not fully understand this answer.  Can you provide a little more context.

Comment: it captures the part `<img src="` before the link into group 1 and the last part of the link into group 2 `image3.jpg">`. replacing all the matched chars with the chars inside group 1 and 2 will give you the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

I would use DOM, SAX or STaX for this, according to the size of your document.

Here's a quick and dirty example with DOM (you'll need to adapt a few changes).

```
String minimalHtml = "<html><head></head><body>" +
        "<img src=\"www.something.com/images/image1.jpg\"></img>" + 
        "<img src=\"www.something.com/images/image2.jpg\"></img>" +
        "<img src=\"www.something.com/images/image3.jpg\"></img>" +
        "</body></html>";
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(minimalHtml)));
NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("img");
for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
    NamedNodeMap nnm = nl.item(i).getAttributes();
    for (int j = 0; j < nnm.getLength(); j++) {
        String oldValue = nnm.item(j).getNodeValue();
        int index = oldValue.lastIndexOf("/") + 1;
        if (index > -1 && index < oldValue.length()) {
            nnm.item(j).setNodeValue(oldValue.substring(index));
        }
    }
}
// printing out doc
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();

transformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(sw));
System.out.println(sw.toString());
```

**Output**

```
<html>
<head>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<img src="image1.jpg"><img src="image2.jpg"><img src="image3.jpg"></body>
</html>
```

Comment: I like this approach, however, my html has embedded jquery in it so not sure how DOM will like that.

Comment: It *shouldn't* be an issue in theory... I'm not knowledgeable in jQuery but I would give it a try nonetheless.

Comment: please add `import` in this code. it is hard for a newbie to java like me to find proper imports files just by looking at the code.

Comment: @SudiptoChandra if you use an IDE and a recent enough version of Java (in this case after Java 5), you don't need to manually import anything - just let the IDE do it for you. E.g. in Eclipse, Ctrl-Shift-O.

Answer (score -1):

```
(<img\s*src=)".*\\
```

Try this.Replace by `$1"`.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/nA6hN9/15